# Show more/less if text does not fit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating some cards with dynamic data using jquery. There is a description property that either fits on the card or not. When it does not fit, i would like to keep the card the same size as the others but add a "show more/less" button that would expand the card to show the rest of the description.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/97533/) showing the card creation as well as what i have tried so far.

At this point i have a function `checkTruncation` that will check if the text would fit in its container or not. The issue seems to rely on the fact that the elements are not yet rendered so their width is 0 which makes the function return always true.

The function is as this:

```
let checkTruncation = function (jqueryElement) {
    var $element = jqueryElement;
    if ($element) {
        var $c = $element
            .clone()
            .css({ display: 'inline', width: 'auto', visibility: 'hidden' })
            .appendTo('body');

        let truncated = $c.width() > $element.width()
        console.log($c.width(), $element.width(), $c.width() > $element.width())
        $c.remove();

        return truncated;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also, instead of me reinventing the wheel, is there any suggested library that could achieve this functionality? I know i have seen such behavior, but cannot remember where.

**UPDATE**

In the fiddle above, i am just calling the getCard function, which is responsible to provide the template for the card, twice just to show some sample. In the real life situation i am getting data through ajax and populating the cards using the following when a user clicks on a button:

```
$('.fetchButton').on('click', function(){
    $.get(url, filter)
        .done(function (data) {
            jQuery.each(data, function (index, item) {
                $('.container').append(getCard(item));
            })
        }
})
```

**UPDATE 2**

With the help of **[@LGSon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396324/show-more-less-if-text-does-not-fit/51397135#51397135)** i have come to this [scenario](https://jsfiddle.net/jyparask/kgcnt2u7/5/) which is mostly using CSS to achieve what i need. Still the answer given is valid and did solve my issue so i will keep it as an answer.

Comment: Have you tried to call the checkTruncation function in $(document).ready(function(){}); ?

Comment: @BrankVictoria the cards are normally created through ajax call based on user interaction. So they are not there on document ready.

Comment: Then where are you calling the checkTruncation function? I believe that you are calling it in the "success" of the ajax call.

Comment: @BrankVictoria I have a fiddle link. In the example i am not using an ajax, just calling an append to the container. But you may imagine that the append will occure within the done or success of an ajax call after getting the results from the server. I will update the question in order to make this more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens beacuse you doesn't append your element to document, so its width is 0. So, update your code as the following:

```js
let checkTruncation = function($element) {
  if ($element) {
    var $c = $element
      .clone()
      .css({ display: 'inline', width: 'auto', visibility: 'hidden' })
      .appendTo('body');

    let truncated = $c.width() > $element.width();
    // console.log($c.width(), $element.width(), $c.width() > $element.width());
    $c.remove();

    return truncated;
  }
    
  return false;
};

let baseUrl ='';

let getCard = function(item, $parent) {
  let outerDiv = $('<div>').addClass('shops-content-right');
  let boxDiv = $('<div>').addClass('boxes-right row');
  let shopDiv = $('<div>').addClass('one-shop-box col-md-6 offset-md-3');
  let cubeDiv = $('<div>').addClass('cube text-center');
  let descriptionP = $('<p>').addClass('text-disc').text(item.description).addClass('collapsed');
  let loadMoreP = $('<p>').css({ 'font-size': '16px', 'cursor': 'pointer' }).text("More >");

  cubeDiv.append(descriptionP).append(loadMoreP);
  shopDiv.append(cubeDiv);
  boxDiv.append(shopDiv);
  outerDiv.append(boxDiv);
  $parent.append(outerDiv);

  loadMoreP.on('click', function () {
    if (descriptionP.hasClass('collapsed')) {
      descriptionP.removeClass('collapsed');
      loadMoreP.text("Less <");
    } else {
      descriptionP.addClass('collapsed');
      loadMoreP.text("More >");
    }
  });

  if (checkTruncation(descriptionP)) {
    loadMoreP.show();
  } else {
    loadMoreP.hide();
  }
};

const $container = $('.container');

getCard({
  description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum'
}, $container);

getCard({
  description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'
}, $container);
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.one-shop-box {
  border:1px solid;
}

.shops-content-right .one-shop-box .cube p.text-disc {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container"></div>
```

I pass to the function `getCard()` the container element, and it append the new element to it before it calls to the function `checkTruncation().`

And update your code that calls `getCard()` as follows:

```
const $container = $('.container');
$('.fetchButton').on('click', function() {
  $.get(url, filter).done(function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
      getCard(item, $container);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to given answer, which explained why the original code didn't work, here is a different approach, showing how one can use CSS to show/hide a *"Read more..."* button

With `absolute: position` and `overflow: hidden` we can *hide* a *"button"* at the bottom of a *"text"* element, and when that element reach the *"wrapper's"* height, the hidden *"button"* becomes visible.

I also made use of a pseudo element and `data-*` attribute to keep *"button text"* in the markup, and the CSS `attr()` to toggle it when showing/hiding the text.

Stack snippet

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.readmore').forEach( function(link) {
  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.closest('.wrapper').classList.toggle('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper.show {
  height: auto;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.readmore {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 52px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
  .readmore::before {
    content: attr(data-more)
  }
  .wrapper.show .readmore {
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    display: block;
  }
  .wrapper.show .readmore::before {
    content: attr(data-less)
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">
    Some smaller dummy text here

    <span class="readmore" data-more="Show more..." data-less="Show less..."></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">
    Some bigger dummy text here <br>
    Some bigger dummy text here <br>
    Some bigger dummy text here <br>
    Some bigger dummy text here <br>
    Some bigger dummy text here <br>
    
    <span class="readmore" data-more="Show more..." data-less="Show less..."></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If possible, the *"Show more/less..."* text can of course be set in the CSS, to simplify maintenance and have it in one place.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.readmore').forEach( function(link) {
  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.closest('.wrapper').classList.toggle('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper.show {
  height: auto;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.readmore {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 52px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
  .readmore::before {
    content: 'Show more...'
  }
  .wrapper.show .readmore {
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    display: block;
  }
  .wrapper.show .readmore::before {
    content: 'Show less...'
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">
    Some smaller dummy text here

    <span class="readmore"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">
    Some bigger dummy text here <br>
    Some bigger dummy text here <br>
    Some bigger dummy text here <br>
    Some bigger dummy text here <br>
    Some bigger dummy text here <br>
    
    <span class="readmore"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Updated based on a comment

Here is an updated Stack snippet version of your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jyparask/kgcnt2u7/)/[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xJOBjx) sample's

```js
let getCard = function(options) {
  let item = options.data;
  let $parent = options.parent;

  let outerDiv = $('<div>').addClass('shops-content-right');
  let boxDiv = $('<div>').addClass('boxes-right row');
  let shopDiv = $('<div>').addClass('one-shop-box col-md-6 offset-md-3');
  let cubeDiv = $('<div>').addClass('cube text-center');

  let wrapperDiv = $('<div>').addClass('wrapper');
  let textDiv = $('<div>').addClass('text');
  let descriptionP = $('<p>').addClass('text-disc').text(item.description);

  let loadMoreP = $('<span>More >').addClass('readmore');

  textDiv.append([descriptionP, loadMoreP]);
  wrapperDiv.append(textDiv);
  cubeDiv
    .append(wrapperDiv);

  shopDiv.append(cubeDiv);
  boxDiv.append(shopDiv);
  outerDiv.append(boxDiv);

  $parent.append(outerDiv);

  loadMoreP.on('click', function() {
    if (wrapperDiv.hasClass('collapsed')) {
      wrapperDiv.removeClass('collapsed');
      loadMoreP.text("More >");
    } else {
      wrapperDiv.addClass('collapsed');
      loadMoreP.text("Less <");
    }
  })

  return outerDiv;
}


$('.fetchButton').on('click', function() {
  getCard({
    data: {
      description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum'
    },
    parent: $('.container'),
    lines: 3
  })
  getCard({
    data: {
      description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur'
    },
    parent: $('.container'),
    lines: 3
  })
})
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.one-shop-box {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.shops-content-right .one-shop-box .cube p.text-disc {
  font-size: 16px;
  /*height: 50px;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper.collapsed {
  height: auto;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.readmore {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 72px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  color: red;
}

.wrapper.collapsed .readmore {
  position: relative;
  top: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <button class="fetchButton">
Fetch Data
</button>

</div>
```

Comment: That is nice as well. Can you makje it expand when the `Read more` is pressed?

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos Updated with an explanation and some more CSS feature

Comment: First of all i should thank you very much on the effort. I really like this answer (and it has a +1 from me). I do have some issues though (ok, i may be overreacting here), but i worry about the browser coverage. For instance i tried this in IE11 and the snippet shows an error. The question of course is who is crazy enough to still use IE11.... but i cannot answer this for my user base. (i have not checked the analytics...).

Comment: On second thought, my fiddle is not loading (actually jsfiddle is not loading at all) either on IE11.... I do wonder if anybody uses that anymore....

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos IE doesn't support arrow function, `.forEach( link => {` ... so I updated my answer and changed to `.forEach( function(link) {`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176235/discussion-between-giannis-paraskevopoulos-and-lgson).

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos I also updated my answer with a link to your Fiddle, one to the updated Codepen and added a working Stack snippet.